# Adding members to a telegram group using their phone number

Tags: python, python-asyncio, telethon

I am creating a bot to read some contact type message in some groups and add those contacts to another group by their phone number.
I tried many ways for doing so as far as trying older versions of telethon, but I still can't add them to a group using phone number.
Is there any way to do this by phone number or did telegram completely block this?
Even if anyone knows a way to find user id by their phone number that would be helpful.